# Jeep-sqlite loader not running in web

Tags: javascript, sqlite, browser, vite

I build an app with [Vite Vue Ionic capacitor 5](https://github.com/jepiqueau/vite-vue-sqlite-app) (latest version) and SQLite. I try to implement packages with `@capacitor-community/sqlite`. On mobile simulator all runs well, but in browser jeep-sqlite.entry.js is not found:

[image]

Initial connection:

```
     state() {
return {
  platform: Capacitor.getPlatform(),
  apiCon: null,
  db: null,
  dbdriver: new SQLiteConnection(CapacitorSQLite),
  network: {
    connected: false,
    connectionType: "none",
  },
};
}

applyPolyfills().then(() => {
        jeepSqlite(window);
      });
      console.log("1");

      // Create the 'jeep-sqlite' Stencil component

      const jeepEl = await document.createElement("jeep-sqlite");
      console.log("2");

      await document.body.appendChild(jeepEl);
      console.log("3");

      await customElements.whenDefined("jeep-sqlite");
      console.log("4");

      // Initialize the Web store

      await this.state.dbdriver.initWebStore();
      console.log("5");
```

Step 1 to 4 is run. How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem in a Vite React Ionic Capacitor setup. You have to exclude jeep-sqlite loader from the optimize deps in your **vite.config.ts**:

```
export default defineConfig({
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: ['jeep-sqlite/loader']
  }
});
```